# What is an ASP.NET web form?

Tags: asp.net, forms, web

I feel a bit silly asking such a simple question.

I'm taking my first web programming course and I just had a quick question about ASP.NET web forms.

What exactly is an ASP.NET web form?

My understanding is that they are web pages that can get information from a user and then process process information on the server. Once processed, the information can be displayed to the user by changing the page's HTML.

I did ask my prof and was told that ASP.NET web forms are simply forms that "inheret from the Page(page?) class". This explanation has left me a bit confused which is why I'm now asking the question...

Am I missing a fundemental concept?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at a tutorial?  http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Form is a Asp.net web design pattern. Where developers develop it as individual forms. (Home.aspx == home page). The Code, Client Script, Server Script, Html, Style Sheet everything is coupled. So it is developed as a form from the scratch. So, when hosted if a user requests Home page, It herits the page class, with its own styles, Html, Codebehind file.

All server controls must appear within a `<form>` tag, and the `<form>` tag must contain the `runat="server"` attribute. The `runat="server"` attribute indicates that the form should be processed on the server. It also indicates that the enclosed controls can be accessed by server scripts:

For deeper information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/what-is-web-forms

Answer (score 0):

everything in the computer is

```
Input -> Processing -> Output
```

not only the asp.net web form.

Especial the asp.net web form, is a way to generate web pages. This is the most simple that I can say, and can be from very simple to very complicate, is a very strong language that can do many more than generates pages. You can start by generate pages, and little by little discover the power with in.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a server side script that gets executed when the server receives a request from the user, it performs some processing and renders a response to the client which is typically an HTML page that gets rendered in a browser.